# Codepen css animation example not working on local

Tags: html, css

I want to use [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/albebonv/pen/DehCH) in my code, but when I copy and pasted the css none of the animation works, I inspected the css using Chrome and all the animation are crossed out, any idea?

```
.loading > div > .c4 {
   top: auto;
   bottom: 10px;
   transform-origin: 20px -4px;
   animation: spin-d 2s infinite cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you try inspecting it in codepen? What difference do you see?

Comment: Have you hovered over the small yellow triangle with the exclamation mark in it and read what it says. I would say it reads something like 'unsupported', try `-webkit-animation` as well as `animation`. It appears that code pen is adding that automagically for you, if you compare the Code pen css to the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome and Safari, you have to use `-webkit-animation`. For Firefox you have to use `-moz-animation`. For Opera you need `-o-animation`. See the [Compatibility Table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Browser_compatibility) in MDN.

Codepen apparently detects the browser version and rewrites the CSS accordingly.

Comment: the `@keyframes` rule will have to be prefixed also i.e. `@-webkit-keyframes`, just so the OP is aware